# Django in docker: ajax POST is failing csrf

Tags: ajax, django, docker, uwsgi, django-csrf

I'm attempting to set up my Django 1.11 application in Docker containers. Here's a summary of what I've done so far:

- Set up docker-compose.yml with an image for redis, django/uwsgi, and jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine. `docker-compose build` runs with no issues.
- Set up my Django code so the client sends an `X-CSRFToken` custom header with each ajax POST request. This works fine when running Django with `runserver`.
- Set up my Django code to use redis as the session cache.
- Added the virtual hosts defined in `docker-compose.yml` to my `/etc/hosts`.
- Set up the virtual host name (`dev.mysite.com`) in Django's `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting.

At this point, I run my Docker setup using `docker-compose up` and I access my site in my browser using the virtual host (`dev.mysite.com`). It works for normal GET requests, but a subsequent ajax POST request fails on CSRF verification with the following CSRF failure reason:

```
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

The original response has a `SET-COOKIE` header with a csrf token that matches the `X-CSRFToken` header that the later ajax request contains. The ajax POST request also has the csrf cookie set, and that cookie also matches the `SET-COOKIE` header from the first request.

At this point, I have no idea why the CSRF token is not verifying in Django's csrf middleware, and I'm especially confused because it works fine with Django's runserver command and even with the `django-extensions`'s `runserver_plus` command when supplied with an ssl cert for https testing.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  django-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DJANGO_ENV: ${DJANGO_ENV}
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=dev.mysite.com
      - VIRTUAL_PROTO=uwsgi
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    sysctls:
      - net.core.somaxconn=1024
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis:/data
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - ENABLE_IPV6=true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./config/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y && \
    pip install uwsgi

ARG DJANGO_ENV=devdocker
ENV DJANGO_ENV=$DJANGO_ENV
ENV UWSGI_INI=/opt/mysite/config/uwsgi/${DJANGO_ENV}.ini
ENV DOCKER_CONTAINER=1
ENV UWSGI_ENV=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings.${DJANGO_ENV}

RUN echo $DJANGO_ENV
COPY . /opt/mysite
WORKDIR /opt/mysite
RUN pip install -r /opt/mysite/requirements/${DJANGO_ENV}.txt
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --settings=mysite.settings.${DJANGO_ENV}
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["sh", "-c", "uwsgi", "--ini", "${UWSGI_INI}"]
```

devdocker.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 0.0.0.0:8000
chdir = /opt/mysite
module = mysite.wsgi
static-map = /static=/opt/mysite/static
master = 1
processes = 2
threads = 2
```

Setup for ajax post requests (from [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request)):

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Note that I have `DBUG = True` in my django settings for the devdocker environment, as well as all of the correct settings for using redis as a session store. Also note that everything except csrf verification is working; GET requests return appropriately and static files are showing up fine.